# CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email) returns null for some people in my organization

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm using `CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email)` in my Google Apps Script. This is working fine for my own calendar, and one other person in the organization. However, this fails (returns null) for many other people, even those that I have full viewing privileges towards.

How do I get this to return their calendar?

Answer (score 2):

You must subscribe to the person's Google Calendar to get this to work. You can do this by choosing:

Add calendar > Subscribe to Calendar

Then entering the person's email address.

This means their calendar must always be visible in the "Other calendars" section of Google Calendar.

---

Another alternative is to use the Advanced Calendar API which doesn't have this requirement!

Comment: do you know how to GROUP_EMAIL subscribe other calendar...? I referenced https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#listing_events .I put a valid calendarId , but response is assigned a different value than my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I wrote to automatically subscribe to all users. You just need to supply the list of emails.

```
  var emails = [] // list all emails here

  emails.forEach((email) => {
    try {
      CalendarApp.subscribeToCalendar(email)
      Logger.log("Email: %s, Timezone: %s", email, CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email).getTimeZone())
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log("this email failed: %s", email)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: It just works for admin email and throws error for all the other emails. so this function needs correction.